# Interface A missing PCB

Tags: technic, powered-up, vintage, education

I have a Technic Interface A with the cables but lack the printed circuit board (PCB) for PC that I need to use it for automating my models. The card when it was for sale had markings of Lego 9771 and I assume this to be the part number.

Ideally I would like an original card but is there a way of getting a 3rd party card? Or another idea might be if someone does manage to make such an interface please consider building it to run multiple Interface A and/or B modules simultaneously.

I think that I may have parts that run on almost if not all of the powered interfaces that Lego has been kind enough to release. I would be quite grateful indeed if I were able to use them together in my sizeable Lego projects.

Comment: Hi Mark and welcome to Bricks.SE! I for one have a hard time picturing your situation as I haven't heard of "Technic Interface A", so could you please upload a photo of your part? The 9771 number does not match any known sets and none of the [matching parts](https://brickset.com/parts?query=9771) are related to Technic.

Comment: Does this help? Technic Interface A on [lgauge.com](https://lgauge.com/technic/LEGOInterfaceA/9750(1093).htm)

Comment: @Uli Thanks, I have learned something new today :)

Answer (score 3):

Uli posted a link in a comment to https://lgauge.com/technic/LEGOInterfaceA/9750(1093).htm which has a link to http://isodomos.com/Lego-Sets/1093.html , that link is dead but archive.org has a copy http://web.archive.org/web/20081121054400/http://isodomos.com/Lego-Sets/1093.html both sites have the pinout, but the latter site also confirms the logic levels as 5V TTL.

I will repeat the pinout here, in case those sites disappear.

- Pins 1 and 3: 5V
- Other odd numbered pins: Ground
- Even numbered pins 6-16: Outputs 0-5
- Pins 18 and 20: Inputs 6 and 7

Unlike the interface B which is a somewhat-intelligent device that communicates over RS-232 the interface A seems to just use straight digital IO lines. For bi-directional control of motors the outputs can be used in pairs.

The pinout seems to be an exact match for the user port on a BBC micro. I suspect this is not a coincidence.

It would not be difficult to hook this up to something more modern, a 5V Arduino could probably hook up directly. For a Raspberry Pi you would want something to shift the levels, I'd probably use HCT logic running off 5V for the signals from the Pi to the interface A (this may not be strictly needed) and LVC logic running off 3.3V for the signals from the interface A to the Pi.

Comment: "[Some findings with Interface A](https://ofalcao.pt/blog/series/lego-interface-a)". Blog post from 2017 (ofalcao.pt)

Comment: Yeah, lots of different ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark I can help you. My website [www.brickhacks.com](http://www.brickhacks.com) is all about Interface A. It has schematics for all of the hardware, etc.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/12035)